# AppleScript to save message into eml file in Outlook 15 for Mac

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

The following AppleScript line is giving an error in Microsoft Outlook 15 for Mac (available from Office 365 or Office 2016 Preview).  It works fine in Outlook 2011 for Mac.  Do you know the AppleScript command to save messages in Outlook 15 for Mac?

```
save theMessage in theFileName
```

For a sample usage of this save command, please refer to the script in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744001/applescript-save-selected-outlook-message-as-eml-file)

Comment: Am I right in assuming you are trying to get this Omnifocus script to work? Did you ever get it to? Thanks http://rainer.4950.net/2014/06/04/outlook-to-omnifocus2-take-12/

Comment: @broderboy Yes, that is what I am trying to do. Let me try to test your suggestion below.  Thanks.

Comment: cool. I also wrapped it in an Alfred workflow that I'm testing out if you use that https://github.com/broderboy/Inbox-Zero-Macros/tree/master/mac/Alfred

Comment: @broderboy Your suggestion to change the temp file location worked great. I am still using OF1 though. And, yes, I switched to Alfred workflow as Outlook 16 removed AppleScript support. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to get this Outlook to Omnifocus script working, http://rainer.4950.net/2014/06/04/outlook-to-omnifocus2-take-12/

Change the save location to be internal to Outlook. I think this has something to do with Sandboxing

```
set theFileName to "/Users/tbroder/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Outlook/Data/Documents/OutlookMsg" & theID & ".eml"
```

This worked for me with the Apple Store version of OmniFocus

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code instead:

```
save theMessage in (theFileName)
```

What file name do you specify for the save command?

Comment: No, that did not help.  File name is a temp file under /tmp.  As I said, this script is working fine on Outlook 2011 for Mac.  Something changed in Outlook 15.